# Proxy timeouts on Java Apache HTTP client

Tags: java, http, proxy

I have a problem with the proxy set on Spring WebTemplate. Building the HTTP Client, org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig.Builder, I set the timeouts:

```
- connectTimeout = 1000
- connectionRequestTimeout = 2000
- socketTimeout = 6000
- proxy = #{ T(org.apache.http.HttpHost).create('${proxyUrl}') }
```

Next I use the above as factory bean into my HttpClientBuilder:

```
<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder">
<property name="defaultRequestConfig">
<bean class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-bean="httpRequestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build"/>
</property>
</bean>
```

and set the WebTemplate messageSender:

```
<property name="messageSender">
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
<constructor-arg>
<bean class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
</property>
```

and WebTemplate

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
            <property name="soapVersion">
                <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11" />
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="defaultUri" value="${endpoint.url}" />
    <property name="messageSender">
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My issue is although I set the timeouts to 1, 2 and 6 seconds, because of the proxy, it takes 75 seconds to get back with an error (most likely from proxy, network unavailable).

If I remove the proxy, the connection times out as expected.

Is there a way to force the timeout using proxy to 1 seconds? Running on JEE container, so spawning another thread is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be because of this bug:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1478

Once added the SocketConfig, the timeout was respected:

```
<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder">
     …….
   <property name="defaultSocketConfig" >
        <bean class="org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig" factory-bean="socketConfigBuilder" factory-method="build"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="socketConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.config.SocketConfig.Builder">
    <property name="soTimeout" value="${connect_timeout}"/>
</bean>
```